# Google Cloud Platform Blocking Network Data from Digitalocean

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, blocked

I have a DigitalOcean droplet from which I am hosting a number of WordPress sites for clients.

One of my clients is attempting to use a premium plugin which is trying to make a call to their server hosted on GCP to authenticate their plugin license.

I've contacted DigitalOcean support and they found that from DO network - we do see the packets are fully leaving our network but being blocked on the end point (GCP).

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Edit:

`Tracepath shows:
tracepath 130.211.95.47
1?: [LOCALHOST] pmtu 1500
1: 178.128.32.253 1.273ms
1: 178.128.32.253 0.469ms
2: 138.197.251.220 0.938ms
3: 5.101.111.253 0.947ms asymm 6
4: 216.239.42.41 1.808ms asymm 5
5: 209.85.143.67 1.694ms
6: 209.85.250.185 1.788ms asymm 5
7: ??? 16.600ms asymm 8
8: 209.85.143.163 9.013ms
9: 209.85.252.59 6.593ms asymm 8
10: no reply
11: no reply
12: no reply
13: no reply
14: no reply
15: no reply
16: no reply
17: no reply
18: no reply
19: no reply
20: no reply
21: no reply
22: no reply
23: no reply
24: no reply
25: no reply
26: no reply
27: no reply
28: no reply
29: no reply
30: no reply
Too many hops: pmtu 1500
Resume: pmtu 1500`

[Image of MTR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIqnk.png)

Comment: This depends entirely on the specific configuration of their GCP network, firewall rules, etc. Without knowing those details, this is impossible to diagnose. GCP itself does not block traffic from anywhere.

Comment: What endpoint? What type of authorization? As Travis mentioned there are no details to review.

Comment: What what does "blocked" mean? Please post the specific error.

Comment: Apologies. I've never had to deal with GCP before.

The current error I have is: cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds.

Edited my original post with a tracepath.

Comment: Like I said, GCP itself doesn't block traffic from anywhere. This plugin server is either unreachable or has misconfigured their GCP networking/firewall rules. If you don't have access to these, you should contact the plugin company and let them know that they need to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you Travis.